# Moving items up in the stack

Tags: stack, gnu-assembler

How does one move items up in the stack?

(Pseudocode, because the code inside and the registers to push will vary.)

```
    push registers to stack
    alter the registers
    get return value on top of the stack
    keep the top of the stack but restore the registers
```

So the stack looks like this:

(Top)

(Return value)

(Register)

(Register)

...

(Register)

And I want to make it look like this:

(Top)

(Return value)

And then have the registers get their values from the stack. Is this at all possible? I am trying to do it in gas. Can this be done? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to put a return value (which you get from...?) before the registers on the stack, then pop the registers, but keep the return value?

One suggestion I could give is to make room for your return value on the stack first (like `subl $4, %esp`, in case your return value is 4 bytes) and then put your return value there, instead of on top of the stack.

Another suggestion (which may be easier to implement), is to make some room in the `.data`section with `.skip`, move the return value there, and then after restoring the registers move it back to the stack.

It's hard to give you a concrete example, since I don't know much about the scenario.